# Is there any better way to do this in C++? Check which numbers satisfy the condition [A*B*C = A! + B! + C!]

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

This is what I came up with

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int serialNumber = 1;
```

Would recursion be better?

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int k=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
    {
        k=k*i;
    }
    return k;
}
```

How can I go about doing this in a single for loop?
Or is this the best way?

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int fact1;
    int fact2;
    int fact3;
    for (a=1;a < 11;a++)
    {
        fact1 = factorial(a);
        for (b=1;b < 11;b++)
        {
            fact2 = factorial(b);
            for (c=1;c < 11;c++)
            {
                fact3 = factorial(c);
                cout << serialNumber << " : ";
                int LHS = fact1 + fact2 + fact3;
                if (LHS == a * b * c)
                {
                    cout << "Pass:" <<"    "<< a << " & " << b << " & " << c << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Fail" <<endl;
                }
                    serialNumber++;
            }
            c = 1;
        }
        b = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am being forced to add more none code into it.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perform the factorial in a for-loop instead of using recursion. And you could maybe tried to compute a,b,c using a single for-loop, instead of doing it 3 times. Im not fully sure yet of the performance gain.

Comment: I tried a bit (cpp.sh/9erjuv), best solution seems to be for-loop to compute it. The "once" version is not that efficient, I though that could be nice, but maybe for large numbers.

Comment: How would I go about doing it in a single for loop?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code are better suited for the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I have posted the question at the site.

Comment: Precalculate all factorial results up to `INT_MAX` and use a simple lookup array.

Comment: @KamilCuk factorial scales very fast and you can only store a few of the results without overflowing uint64_t

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is helps,but>
check for minimum of A,B,C

```
A!+B!+C! = (min(A,B,C)!)*(1+((min+1..restfact1)!)+((min+1..restfact2)!))
```

So, you can calculate the minimum factorial and than re-use it for calculating others. 
On the other hand, you can calculate only the maximum factorial and store its results in the array, and re-use pre-calculated values for finding factorial of smaller numbers

Other implication is that the minimum number can be reduced

```
restfact1 * restfact2 = ((min-1)!)*(1+((min+1..restfact1)!)+((min+1..restfact2)!))
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the question was how can this be done in a single loop and this is one way to do that.

I don't think this is a better way of doing it, but the question was asked:

```
    constexpr int bound = 10;
    int Factorials[bound + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= bound; ++i) Factorials[i] = Factorial(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < bound * bound * bound; ++i) {
        int s = i + 1;
        int a = i;
        int c = 1 + a % bound;
        a /= bound;
        int b = 1 + a % bound;
        a /= bound;
        ++a;

        cout << s << " : ";
        int LHS = Factorials[a] + Factorials[b] + Factorials[c];
        if (LHS == a * b * c)
            ...
    }
```